# Variance of the sum of 3 Pairwise Independent random variables

Tags: probability, variance

We have 3  independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter 1/2. They are pairwise independent but not mutually independent.
I know that the variance of Var[A] = Var[B] = Var [C] = 0.25 due to the formula of Bernoulli random variables variance: p * (1-p).
Therefore, I know that Var[A] + Var[B] + Var [C] = 0.75.
I know as well that Var[A + B + C] = 0.75 because Var[A + B + C] = Var[A] + Var[B] + Var [C] when the variables are pairwise independent.

However, **I am not able to calculate by myself Var[A + B + C]**. Can you please guide mr algebraically?

Thanks

Comment: Start with  $\mathsf{Var}(A+B+C)=\mathsf{Covar}(A+B+C,A+B+C)$ and make use of bilinearity of covariance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\mathrm{Var}(A+B+C)=\mathrm{Cov}(A+B+C,A+B+C)=\mathrm{Var}(A)+\mathrm{Var}(B)+\mathrm{Var}(C)+2\mathrm{Cov}(A,B)+2\mathrm{Cov}(A,C)+2\mathrm{Cov}(B,C)$$
In order for the variance of the sum to be the sum of the variance you don't even need anything as strong as pairwise independence; it is enough for the covariance of each pair to be $0$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess all covariances are 0 due to pairwise independence?

Comment: @Bob Yes that's right

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to solve it by the following formula as well? Var[A+B+C] =E[(A+B+C)2]−(E[A+B+C])2

Comment: @Bob You'll end up using the covariance anyway.